# How to find similar results from all rows in DB with MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to make "Search you'r LOGIN" like in facebook :

Eg. searching for "Stock Overflow" would return

```
Stack Overflow
SharePoint Overflow
Math Overflow
Politic Overflow
VFX Overflow
```

Eg. searching for "LO" would return:

```
pabLO picasso
michelangeLO
jackson polLOck
```

Eg. searching for username "user123" would return :

```
 user123
 user1234
 and etc ...
```

My Database rows :

```
userid  |   username  |  useremail   |  user_fname   |  user_lname
```

I would like to make a search input that search the word in any of this rows like above examples,

Here my php till now :

```
$string = $purifier->purify(@$_POST['string']); 

          $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_fname = '".$string."' OR user_lname = '".$string."' OR username = '".$string."' OR useremail= '".$string."'";
          mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
          $result2 = mysql_query($query);
          $num = mysql_num_rows($result2);

          if($num == 1)
          {
              //true
          }else{

              //not found nothing
          }
```

this way is not working good , and its not return all the similar reuslts of the word that i put in search input.
plus how i return it with foreach if there is more then 1 similar result ?

Thanks allot.

**Update :**

Thanks all , my updated code to fix it :

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_fname like '%".$string."%' OR user_lname like '%".$string."%' OR username like  '%".$string."%' OR useremail like '%".$string."%'";
```

and i am not using mysql , just for the examples i had more easy to do like this..

Comment: use 'like %sometext%'

Comment: like %% in all rows like i did ?

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20186289/829533

Comment: also you must know that mysql_* functions are depreciated http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/829533

Comment: i using mysqli prepared , here i used normal mysql for test its more easer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$string = $purifier->purify(@$_POST['string']); 

      $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_fname like '%".$string."%' OR user_lname like '%".$string."%' OR username like  '%".$string."%' OR useremail like '%".$string."%'";
      mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
      $result2 = mysql_query($query);
      $num = mysql_num_rows($result2);

      if($num == 1)
      {
                //true
              }else{

                 //not found nothing
              }
```

Comment: i wil test it , 1 moment.

Comment: in case of `user123` this query will search for `user1234` and `Auser123` too

Comment: yea this what i need , thanks i just have problem with utf8 when i put text in Hebrew , i dont get any result and say wrong all time. i will flag your post as accepted soon as the system will give me,i need wait few minutes.

Comment: @zzlalani according to user need its work because its used `OR`operator here

Answer (score 0):

Change your query with this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_fname LIKE '".$string."%' OR user_lname LIKE '".$string."%' OR username LIKE '".$string."%' OR useremail LIKE '".$string."%'";
```

**NOTE:**

If you have `user123` keyword and you want to make a search for all the rows that have data `user123*` you can apply the wildcard `$string%`

And in case of `*user123*` you can use `%$string%`

And in case of `*user123` you can use `%$string`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_fname like '%".$string."%' OR user_lname like '%".$string."%' OR username like '%".$string."%' OR useremail like '%".$string."'%";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_fname LIKE '%".$string."%' OR user_lname = '%".$string."%' OR username = '%".$string."%' OR useremail= '%".$string."%'";
```

for info for [Like keyword](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-like-clause.htm)

**Note**

- Please avoid mysql_*... use mysqli_* or PDO

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE user_fname LIKE '%$string%' 
OR user_lname LIKE '%$string%' 
OR username LIKE '%$string%' 
OR useremail LIKE '%$string%'";
```